# ML.NET Input shape mismatch when loading SSD Inception v2 model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, ml.net

I am trying to load a tensorflow model of SSD Inception v2 model in the ".pb" format into a ML.NET, but I am keep getting the following  "shape mismatch" error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Input shape mismatch: Input 'image_tensor' has shape (-1, -1, -1, 3), but input data is of length 691200.'
```

To load the model Im using the following code:

```
            var pipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(resizing: ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.Fill, outputColumnName: "data", imageWidth: 640, imageHeight: 360, inputColumnName: nameof(ImageInputData.Image))
            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "image_tensor", inputColumnName: "data", outputAsFloatArray: false))
            .Append(_mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(tfModelFilePath)
                                .ScoreTensorFlowModel(
                                    outputColumnNames: InputImageSettings.OutputNodes,
                                    inputColumnNames: InputImageSettings.InputNodes,
                                    addBatchDimensionInput: false));


        var emptyData = new List<ImageInputData>();
        var data = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(emptyData);

        ITransformer mlModel = pipeline.Fit(data);
```

What does the error message says? It is comparing data shape to the data length. How is it relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was caused by the bug in ML.NET ([see the issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5286)). The next release of the package will fix it.